# XPath Selector Join Elements

Tags: xpath

I need to use XPath to select and return the values of elements "Longitude" and "Latitude" in the below XML.

```
<LocationsList>
    <Locations>
        <Id>31dbwlph0yi--1</Id>
        <Latitude>45.352304</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-75.724945</Longitude>
    </Locations>
    <Locations>
        <Id>600001-0-0--1</Id>
        <Latitude>45.33142</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-79.96399</Longitude>
    </Locations>
</LocationsList>
```

Here's what I need my XPath to return (where one list item returns both Latitude and Longitude):

```
1. 45.352304 -75.724945
2. 45.33142 -79.96399
```

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble.   Here's what I've tried...

**XPath `LocationsList/Locations` returns:**

```
1. 31dbwlph0yi--1 45.352304 -75.724945
2. 600001-0-0--1 HWY 400 45.33142 -79.96399
```

**XPath `LocationsList/Locations/(Latitude | Longitude)` returns:**

```
1. 45.35304
2. -75.724945
3. 45.33142
4. -79.96399
```

**XPath `LocationsList/Locations/concat(Latitude, " ", Longitude)` returns a string:**

```
Non-standard output:
45.352304 -75.724945
45.33142 -79.96399
```

Comment: Your last XPath seems to be correct. What am I missing?

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed It's returning a string instead of selecting the nodes.

I want 
```1. 45.352304 -75.724945
2. 45.33142 -79.96399```

but I get a string: ```45.352304 -75.724945
45.33142 -79.96399```

Comment: So you want XPath to return *list of lists of nodes*? I'm not sure why you want exactly this output and I don't think it's possible... Also your expected output actually looks like a concatenated strings so you'd better to update question with exact output

Comment: Injecting an integer sequence (1, 2, etc.) isn’t possible with XPath.  It’s easy with XQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to XPath 3.1, there's no array data type in the data model. The best you could do is return a sequence, but NB there's no such thing as a sequence of sequences; a sequence is necessarily a flat list. Let's see how this works with your sample data:

```
<LocationsList>
    <Locations>
        <Id>31dbwlph0yi--1</Id>
        <Latitude>45.352304</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-75.724945</Longitude>
    </Locations>
    <Locations>
        <Id>600001-0-0--1</Id>
        <Latitude>45.33142</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-79.96399</Longitude>
    </Locations>
</LocationsList>
```

Take this one of your expressions:

```xpath
/LocationsList/Locations/concat(Latitude, " ", Longitude)
```

It produces a sequence of 2 strings which each contain a latitude and a longitude value, separated by a space:

```
("45.352304 -75.724945", "45.33142 -79.96399")
```

Or you could use an expression like this to select a sequence of either `Latitude` or `Longitude` elements and convert them to numbers:

```xpath
LocationsList/Locations/(Latitude | Longitude)/number(.)
```

That returns a sequence of 4 numbers, which are alternately latitude and longitude values

```
(45.352304,-75.724945,45.33142,-79.96399)
```

Finally, in XPath 3.1 you have support for an `array` datatype, so you can iterate over the sequence of Locations and construct an array from each one, and return a sequence of arrays:

```xpath
for $location in 
  /LocationsList/Locations 
return 
  [number($location/Latitude), number($location/Longitude)]
```

The result is this sequence of arrays, each containing 2 numbers:

```
([45.352304,-75.724945], [45.33142,-79.96399])
```

Or if you want to get fancy you could return an array of arrays:

```xpath
fold-left(
  for $location in 
    /LocationsList/Locations 
  return 
    [number($location/Latitude), number($location/Longitude)],
  [],
  function($array, $location) {
    Q{http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array}append($array, $location)
  }
)
```

... giving:

```
[[45.352304,-75.724945],[45.33142,-79.96399]]
```